# How to import keras model (version 1.2.0) using keras (version 2.4.3)

Tags: keras

I want to load the model which was trained using an old keras framework (1.2.0). Currently I am using 2.4.3 version of keras. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can downgrade your keras application using:

```
pip install keras == 1.2.0
```